# Finding the last 4, 3, 2, 1 months consecutive order drops among clients based on drop variance

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here I have this query that finds out the drop percentage of a bunch of clients based on the orders they have received(i.e. It finds the percentage difference in orders by comparing the current month with the previous month). What I want to achieve here is to have a field where I can see the clients who had 4 months continuous drop, 3 months drop, 2 months drop, and 1 month drop.

I know, it can only be achieved by comparing the last 4 months using the lag function or sub queries. can you guys pls help me out on this one, would appreciate it very much

```
select
fd.customers2, fd.Month1, fd.year1, fd.variance, case when 
 (fd.variance < -0.00001 and fd.year1 = '2022.0' and fd.Month1 = '1')
 then '1month drop' else fd.customers2 end as 1_most_host_drop


from 

(SELECT
c.*,
sa.customers as customers2,
sum(sa.order) as orders,
date_part(mon, sa.date) as Month1,
date_part(year, sa.date) as year1,
(cast(orders - LAG(orders) OVER(Partition by customers2 ORDER BY 
 year1, Month1) as NUMERIC(10,2))/NULLIF(LAG(orders)  
OVER(partition by customers2 ORDER BY year1, Month1) * 1, 0)) AS variance
FROM stats sa join (select distinct
    d.id, d.customers 
     from configer d 
    ) c on sa.customers=c.customers
WHERE sa.date >= '2021-04-1' 
GROUP BY Month1, sa.customers, c.id,  year1, 
     c.customers)fd
```

Comment: Amazon redshift and mysql are two different database productd. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Shadow redshift is what i use.

Answer (score 0):

In a spirit of friendliness: I think you are a little premature in posting this here as there are several issues with the syntax before even reaching the point where you can solve the problem:

1. You have at least two places with a comma immediately preceding the word `FROM`:

   ...AS variance, FROM stats_archive sa ...

   ...d.customers, FROM config d...
2. Recommend you don't use VARIANCE as an alias (it is a system function in PostgreSQL and so is likely also a system function name in Redshift)
3. Not super important, but there's no need for `c.*` - just select the columns you will use
4. `DATE_PART` requires a string as the first parameter `DATE_PART('mon',current_date)`
5. I might be wrong about this, but I suspect you cannot use column aliases in the `partition by` or `order by` of a window function. Put the originating expressions there instead:

   ... OVER (PARTITION BY customers2 ORDER BY DATE_PART('year',sa.date),DATE_PART('mon',sa.date))
6. `LAG` has three parameters. (1) The column you want to retrieve the value from, (2) the row offset, where a positive integer indicates how many rows prior to the current row you should retrieve a value from according to the partition and order context and (3) the value the function should return as a default (in case of the first row in the partition). As such, you don't need `NULLIF`. So, to get the row immediately prior to the current row, or return 0 in case the current row is the first row in the partition:

   LAG(orders,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY customers2 ORDER BY DATE_PART('year',sa.date),DATE_PART('mon',sa.date))
7. If you use 0 as a default in the calculation of what is currently aliased `variance`, you will almost certainly run into a `div/0` error either now, or worse, when you least expect it in the future. You should protect against that with some `CASE` logic or better, provide a more appropriate default value or even better, calculate the `LAG` with the default 0, then filter out the 0 rows before doing the calculation.
8. You can't use column aliases in the `GROUP BY`. You must reference each field that is not participating in an aggregate in the group by, whether through direct mention (`sa.date`) or indirectly in an expression (`DATE_PART('mon',sa.date)`)
9. Your date should be `'2021-04-01'`

All in all, without sample data, expected results using the posted sample data and without first removing syntax errors, it is a tall order to attempt to offer advice on the problem which is any more specific than:

Build the source of the calculation as a completely separate query first. Calculate the `LAG` in that source query. Only when you've run that source query and verified that the `LAG` is producing the correct result should you then wrap it as a sub-query or CTE (not sure if Redshift supports these, but presumably) at which point you can filter out the rows with a zero as the denominator (the first month of orders for each customer).

Good luck!